# How to make a dependent dropdowns in React with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web, tsx

I have two dropdowns, base dropdown lists the values Asset & Liability and i need to show the list of second dropdown depended by the base dropdown, ie, if i select Asset the second dropdown only lists Fixed Assets  and Current Assets or if i select Liability then Long term and Short Term. How to do it in React Js With Type script language?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and please add code to show what you have tried.

Comment: If you provide some code, I believe this can be an easy question to answer.

Comment: @Michael thank you for your reply, i'm new to react and at the beginning level. example: it just like select a country from country dropdown and the second dropdown listing only the cities of that country. i don't know how could i provide codes  your need